# Inserting newline character after every 76 characters in a base64 string

Tags: python, base64

I am trying to convert bitmap images into a base64 string before inserting it into database as binary blobs. The base64 string needs to be encoded in such a way that their is a new line character after every 76 characters. What is the best pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
'\n'.join(s[pos:pos+76] for pos in xrange(0, len(s), 76))
```

Answer (score 12):

**For Python version 3:**

```
import base64
base64.encodebytes(s)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.encodebytes

> Encode the bytes-like object s, which can contain arbitrary binary data, and return bytes containing the base64-encoded data, with newlines (b'\n') inserted after every 76 bytes of output, and ensuring that there is a trailing newline, as per RFC 2045 (MIME).

Example:

```
>>> print(base64.encodebytes(b'a' * 100).decode())
YWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFh
YWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYQ==

>>>
```

**For Python version 2:**

```
import base64
base64.encodestring(s)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html

> Encode the string s, which can contain arbitrary binary data, and return a string containing one or more lines of base64-encoded data. encodestring() returns a string containing one or more lines of base64-encoded data always including an extra trailing newline ('\n').

The docs for version 2 could certainly be written more clearly, but it does what you want.

Example:

```
>>> print base64.encodestring('a'*100)
YWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFh
YWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYQ==

>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want line break, don't use the straight base64 package, use the one provided in email:

```
import email
print email.base64MIME.encode(your_string)
```

It do split the encoded string each 76 characters

Answer (score 1):

Since Base64 mandates a fixed line length (64 or 76 characters, depending on [which version you look at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table)), the library that produces the Base64 String should already do that (or at least have an option to do that).

Answer (score 0):

You should use strict encoding. That will add a new line

```
'your_string_goes_here'.encode('base64', 'strict')
```

Comment: This adds a newline. Try a longer string & you'll see. Also, "...'strict', meaning that encoding errors raise a UnicodeError)" https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=encode#str.encode